# How do you add a custom authorization header to a Windows Store App OData client?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, wcf-data-services, odata, windows-store-apps

I'm building a Windows Store App using the Windows Runtime. I'm accessing an OData service that uses Basic authentication. I'm using the [WCF Data Services Tools for Windows Store Apps](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30714) library (`Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.WindowsStore`).

The authentication string is a custom format, so I can't just use a `NetworkCredential(username, password)`. I need to add the header myself to every request from my `DataServiceContext`.

I tried using the following code:

```
proxy.SendingRequest += (s, e) =>
{
   e.RequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
}
```

But I receive the error:

```
'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection' could be found
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the new [SendingRequest2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.sendingrequest2.aspx) event that fires after the request is built and before it is sent to the server.

There is a [RequestMessage.SetHeader(headername, value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.odata.iodatarequestmessage.setheader) method that you can use to set headers. Set the value to `null` to remove a header.

```
proxy.SendingRequest2 += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    eventArgs.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authorization", authHeader);
};
```

The [WCF Data Services team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/09/26/wcf-data-service-5-1-0-rc2-released.aspx) talks more about it:

> SendingRequest2 (and its deprecated predecessor SendingRequest) fires
>   after the request is built. WebRequest does not allow you to modify
>   the URL after construction. The new event lets you modify the URL
>   before we build the underlying request, giving you full control over
>   the request.

Comment: you asked and answered your own question in a short time. what's the point?

Comment: @lontivero to make the internet better http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Helped me. Thanks.